# idiom to treat empty result set as zero

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This is obviously a SSCCE.

I have an `inventory` table that holds the number of items (`numOfItems`) in a warehouse at any given date (`inventoryDate`). Both are integers to keep things simple:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory(inventoryDate INTEGER, numOfItems INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE inventory ADD PRIMARY KEY (inventoryDate);
```

Now I have some entries:

```
INSERT INTO inventory(inventoryDate, numOfItems) VALUES(1,250),(2,275)
```

What the above says is that on time `1` there were 250 items in the warehouse and on time `2` there were 275.

Now I want to test whether, at the latest date, the number of items in the warehouse exceeded 1000:

```
SELECT 1000<(SELECT numOfItems FROM inventory ORDER BY inventoryDate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

The above seems to work. However, on the edge case that there are no entries at all in the `inventory` table it's not working:

```
DELETE FROM inventory;
SELECT 1000<(SELECT numOfItems FROM inventory ORDER BY inventoryDate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

... returns:

```
?column?
(null)
```

I would like to treat the edge case where there are no entries at all as denoting zero (0) items. I know I can always initialize the `inventory` table with a fake first entry with a value of zero but like I said this is an SSCCE (in my real case this table is really a view which I don't want to modify).

So I end up writing the query like this:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT numOfItems FROM inventory ORDER BY inventoryDate DESC LIMIT 1)
SELECT 1000 < (
CASE 
WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte) THEN 0
         ELSE  (SELECT numOfItems FROM cte)
END)
```

The above does seem to work. But, is there a more idiomatic way? Something like a `COALESCE` but for an empty result set instead of null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `coalesce` outside the subquery expression.

```
SELECT 1000 < coalesce((SELECT numOfItems FROM inventory ORDER BY inventoryDate DESC LIMIT 1), 0);
```

Comment: yeah, I tried `SELECT coalesce(numOfItems)` which wasn't working but I wasn't aware that I could wrap the entire `SELECT` query with it.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus A scalar subquery is just an expression that evaluates to a value, and you can use `coalesce` on any expression.

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` in an outer `SELECT` does the job for a single value. Wouldn't work for selecting **multiple columns or rows**, though.

This technique with `UNION ALL` works **universally**:

```
(
SELECT numofitems   -- or more columns
FROM   inventory
ORDER  BY inventorydate DESC NULLS LAST -- add NULLS LAST if you col isn't NOT NULL!
LIMIT  1            -- or more rows
)
UNION  ALL
SELECT NULL         -- or more columns (matching)
LIMIT 1;
```

Or `SELECT 0` instead of `SELECT NULL` to save another `COALESCE`.
Parentheses around first `SELECT` are not optional.

[More details in this related answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)